# How to Write Jmeter User Function for increasing date?

Tags: jmeter

My thread group consists 30 user. I want to run every user for every date in a month.
Suppose, user1 request date of January 1, user2  request january2 and continue. In this way, I will be covered all the date in a month. For this, how I design my Test Plan, and how to write date function so that after every request date will increase automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're looking for a Stepping Thread Group which is located under the Thread Groups category.

It allows to increment the number of threads, ramp-up and ramp-down periods (don't use ramp-up period in your case as it doesn't make much sense), etc.

The next thing you need to do is to define the `${__P(date)}` property and pass the date in the format acceptable for `SimpleDateFormat` function. The function will return the date in the format you specify, for example:
`${__P(date)} -> 2019-01-01
${__P(date)} -> 2019-01-02
...`

As you can see from the above example the `__P()` function is quite flexible, it can be used for storing dates, URLs, usernames, passwords, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) like:

```
${__groovy(new Date().plus(ctx.getThreadNum() + 1).format('MMMM d'),)}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: can you show me  which sampler are you used and thread group? Because I'm a fresher